# opencv read() function is just working well from python idle shell. works bad from python ./image_handler.py

Tags: opencv, python-idle

I wanna use opencv to grab frame from a webcamera as a common use function API.

The code as following only works well from python idle invoking (frame is not empty, data is good with image get from webcamera, *cap.imshow* function display normal video/picture from camera). but not work well when **not** invoking from python idle (frame data is almost empty, and *cap.imshow* function display almost black screen video/picture from camera).

**I do not know why it does not work from python module invoke from interpreter out of idle?**

**And how to fix this issue? thanks if anyone can give me any suggestion or guides!!!**

**References:**

**CODE:**

```
import cv2
def get_images_via_opencv():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    print(cap.isOpened())
    print(ret)
    print(frame)
    # print(decode_fourcc(cap.get(6)))
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.imwrite('capture.jpg', frame)
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

get_images_via_opencv()
```

Result from python IDLE execution - normal video/image:

```
True
True
[[[  5   4   8]
  [  5   4   8]
  [  5   3   9]
  ...
  [ 85  99 137]
  [ 83  98 134]
  [ 80  95 131]]

 ...
```

Result from other ways - with black screen video/image:

```
True
True
[[[ 80   1 210]
  [187 118   2]
  [  0   0 144]
  ...
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]
  ...
```

Comment: As an IDLE maintainer, the main thing I can think of would only be relevant if cv2 used tkinter.  I doubt, but you could check.  Another possibility would be if your minimal complete code were missing an import, but then I would expect an Exception when not running in IDLE.

Comment: Thanks Terry for the comments!yes I ignore the import statement. the difference is not reasonable from my understanding.

Comment: code executing has not exception, just the frame image from camera has no data/picture while I execute the function out of Python IDLE. 

the point one you mention if python-opencv2 is implemented based on cv2, any workaround or solution to fix this? I will check whether the cv2 is based on tkinter, then feed back to you.

Comment: At this point, I suggest asking any pycv2 forum or its devs, giving full code, OS info, and python version. The difference between python executing your code directly versus being asked by IDLE is the content of sys.modules and sys.stdxx.  None of this should affect the actual image capture.  IDLE sys changes should not make image capture work better.

Comment: it is resolved by a lot of trouble shoting.